# WCF Polymorphic Parameter

Tags: vb.net, wcf, serialization, soap

I have a WCF service that exposes a function:

```
Public Function FeedAnimal(ByVal animal As Animal) As Animal Implements IFarm.FeedAnimal
    animal.Feed()
    Return animal;
End Function
```

However Animal is an abstract class with many derived types, each with their own properties. When I make a request in SOAPUI with the properties that would indicate a Cow, however, I get an error that I cannot create an abstract class. How do I get WCF to deserialize the parameter into its actual type? Let's assume they are all distinguishable by their differently named properties.

I have already tried adding the KnownType attribute everywhere it will go, to no avail. Doing that allowed me to *return* derived types, but not accept them as parameters.

If what I'm trying to do is totally crazy, please tell me the next closest thing

**Edited; I would be satisfied if I can make it fall back to the XmlSerializer for this function only, which used to work in a previous version**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace:=Constants.SERVICE_NAMESPACE)]
[ServiceKnownType(GetType(Cow))]
Public Interface IFarm
    [OperationContract()]
    [ServiceKnownType(GetType(Cow))]
    [Validation(CheckAssertions:=False, SchemaValidation:=True)]
    Function FeedAnimal(ByVal animal As Animal) _
        As Animal
End Interface
```

And the classes

```
[KnownType(GetType(Cow))]
Public MustInherit Class Animal
    Public weight As Integer
End Class

Public Class Cow
    Inherits Animal
    Public mooPower As Double
End Class
```

And the request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:v3="mycomapnyaddresss" xmlns:foo="animalnamespace">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
  <v3:FeedAnimal>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <v3:animal>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <foo:weight>100</foo:weight>
        <foo:mooPower>10.0</foo:mooPower>
     </v3:animal>
  </v3:FeedAnimal>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [ServiceKnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute?

There is a blog post here [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/06/06/618877.aspx) that explains it quite well.

ServiceKnownType goes on the actual service interface itself...

Comment: I've added ServiceKnownType to the interface itself and to the method definition

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the [KnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) attribute to the contract:

```
<DataContract(), KnownType(GetType(Cow)), KnownType(GetType(Dog))> _
Public Class Animal
   ...
End Class
```

Comment: I've already added KnownType to the abstract class. This allowed me to return a value typed as Animal. However, I still can't convince it to deserialize the request parameter as a Cow

Comment: Post the relevant Data and Service Contracts.